# c# - Apply an XSD schema to a SQL based dataset

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xsd, dataset

I googled furiously but couldn't figure this out:

I have a SQL query producing a dataset. I need it grouped in a specific way and outputted to an XML file. So I used an existing XML file in the right format to generate an XSD file in VS. But how do I tell C# to transform my datasets into this format? I used the ReadXMLSchema method of the dataset, but it doesn't apply the schema. Code below. Thanks in advance.

```
da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(myString, conn);
DataSet dSet = new DataSet(@"myDataSetName");
dSet.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\Generated.xsd");  
da.Fill(dSet, "MyAdapter");

System.IO.StreamWriter fileStream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filenamepath);          
dSet.WriteXml(fileStream);
```

Edit: Schema and query posted as per request. All database rows with the same GroupId are grouped, and each row must be grouped by an  tag:

```
SELECT   AsOfDate, GroupId, DesignationDate,   secid "ExternalId", 'Y'     Type,   PctOf, Strategy  
FROM MyTables
WHERE date = '?'      
AND classification = 'LE'     
AND type IN (1,2,3)     
AND ind = 'ZML'   


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyGroup">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GroupID" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ItemInstance">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="DesignationDate" type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="ExternallID" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PctOf" type="xs:decimal" />
              <xs:element name="AsOfDate" type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="Strategy" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Please post the schema and query.

Comment: Schema and query added.